# What would earth's wind look like without differential heating?

Tags: atmospheric-science, geophysics

If the earth were not subject to differential (solar) heating, but otherwise had the same atmospheric and surface temperatures, and same rate of rotation: What would its wind look like?

E.g.:

1. Would the atmosphere even have wind patterns?
2. Would the wind patterns be primarily (or virtually entirely) the result of differential rotation speeds by latitude?
3. Would stable wind patterns like those observable on gas giants emerge?

Comment: Excuse me but what do you mean by the atmosphere would have the same temperature? It does vary with altitude and other factors than solar exposure, such as ground temperature due to other factors including geothermal activity.

Comment: @Exocytosis – I mean "uniform temperature" for purposes of the question.  So yes it varies by altitude based on decreasing pressure, radiation, etc., but let us assume that geothermal heating is uniform around the sphere.  I.e., the atmosphere is not being subject, ex ante, to any exogenous sources of differential heating.